# Software with support for Database with opening analysis

Tags: opening, engines, software

I'm looking for a software tool that will:

1. **Engine Support**. For analysis suggestions.

   - **Support for software evaluation of the moves**. I guess this is optional, although I've seen this feature in popular websites where they give a weight on each move. +1.5, -.8, etc, but what is needed is at least give an arbitrary/subjective weight/evaluation on them with a comment as a justification (just an Idea) as comparison.
2. **Organize the moves variations (from the Opening) with trees**. The only tool that I've seen that has this feature is [chessmaster](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chessmaster) series, other tools have a similar approach but not with trees but a list of the next "registered" variations/moves, this will be acceptable as well, although a tree will be definitely optimal

   - **Rearrange variations on the tree by weight**. Optional. Also seen on chessmaster but in chessmaster it is shown as a 3 star rating on the move so if the moves/variations have weights on them, those can be used to list them in order under the tree.
3. **Support for opening books and easy way to expand them**. I want to be able to add a fairly complete Opening book like "olympiad.abk" and expand it, with new options in the openings and add comments on the different variations.

I've analyzed several tools like the ones I mentioned and [chess.com](https://www.chess.com/analysis), [arena](http://www.playwitharena.de/), [lichess.org](https://lichess.org/analysis) and seeing some others, and I can see that these features exist but I'm thinking that no one has them all.

Do you know any tool that has all these features? Or can you think of something even remotely similar?

Comment: Why would you want a piece of software with those features?

Comment: It is going to be hard to describe but basically to study, document leaned openings variants and grow them as you learn them, I always use it after a serious match or after I face a new variant

Comment: Then you need to get your hands on some ChessBase!

Answer (score 1):

I found a software that complies with the specifications, at least most of them, it is pretty good and personally I really liked it, its name is [CHESS POSITION TRAINER](http://www.chesspositiontrainer.com) and is a paid software. Thank you everybody.